# Rails/Devise - recoverable password not working in production (works in development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am using Devise for user authentication in my Rails app, and I am working on setting up the recoverable password feature.  I am able to get this working correctly in my local development environment, but when I deploy to Heroku, it does not work.

In `config/environments/development.rb`, I have

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost'}
```

which works perfectly.

In `config/environments/production.rb`, I have

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'fake-name-92356.herokuapp.com'}
```

but this generates an error page and the message in my log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true)
```

I have tried various solutions, such as using

```
default_url_options[:host] = 'fake-name-92356.herokuapp.com'
```

but to no avail.  What am I doing wrong here, that this works in development but not in production?

Comment: And I've restarted the Heroku server after pushing the app back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work as Heroku does not provide an email service. These are facilitated by Add-ons.

> The Heroku platform itself doesn’t provide an email service - but
>   instead provides add-ons that act as backing services - that can be
>   attached to your app to provide the service. Consult the Heroku
>   Add-ons marketplace for an appropriate email service that matches your
>   requirements.

Taken from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Comment: For anyone who happens upon this, @patrick 's answer helped me to find this resource - https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/